# PyCharm: Configuring multi-hop remote Interpreters via SSH

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, ssh-tunnel

To connect to the computer at my office I need to run ssh twice. First to connect to the host-1 and then from host-1 to host-2 and each one has different credentials. However the configuration menu in Pycharm only accepts one ssh tunnel.

[Configure Remote Python Interpreter dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE7Sz.jpg)

Is there any way to set a multi-hop ssh to have access to the interpreter and data files on the host from local?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use port forwarding on ssh.

#### 1. Open a terminal and run:

On your local system:

```
ssh -L 6000:<target_server_ip>:22 <proxy_server_user>@<proxy_server_ip>
```

You should be connected to the **proxy** now. You can substitute 6000 with any port.

#### 2. (optional) Test

Now you can ssh into the **target** server on another terminal with:

```
ssh -p 6000 <target_server_user>@localhost
```

#### 3. Configure PyCharm

Keep in mind not to close the first terminal!

The same goes for the PyCharm. Just set the remote interpreter connection through ssh with the following configuration:

- host: localhost
- port: 6000
- user: target_server_user

Comment: I tried this, but am getting the following error: `Could not list the contents of "sftp://127.0.0.1:9999/" because it is not a folder`

Comment: what if the connection was from b to c was established via ssh reverse tunnel?

Comment: Check ~/.ssh/known_hosts and remove any hosts that is causing the problem

Comment: Your solution works. However, it always requires password when I ssh into the target server in step 2. Is there any way to make it password-less?

Comment: @ThangM.Pham Have you tried copying your public ssh rsa key to the server?

Comment: @AHA I tried but it did not work. It turns out that Pycharm was required root permission to read/write so it asked for password all the time. I just need to use `chown` to grant permission for the specific user and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

PyCharm seemingly parses the local .ssh/config too.

If you already have configured ssh hopping there, you can just specify the target server in your pycharm ssh-config.

~/.ssh/config ([source](https://blog.linuxserver.io/2016/12/02/perform-multiple-ssh-hops-with-ssh-config/))

```
Host bastion
   Hostname bastion.domain.com
   Port 2222 # a non-standard port is a good idea
   User ironicbadger

Host servera
   Hostname servera.lan.local
   User servera-user
   ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

in pycharm:
Host `servera`, User name `server-user`

Comment: This solution is much better than the accepted answer in case you have ssh config file already setup.

Comment: In [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/12/creating-a-development-environment-on-amazon-ec2/), in the **"Setting up PyCharm"** part they also explain the same setup. One extra thing you have to do is to set "Authentication type" to "OpenSSH Config and authentication agent".

Comment: Does anybody know how this might be achieved on windows?

Comment: @mkohler this also works on windows (10+)

Answer (score 5):

For users on ssh version 7.3 or later this can be simplified using the `ProxyJump` parameter.

```
Host bastion
   Hostname bastion.domain.com
   User bastion-user

Host servera
   Hostname servera.lan.local
   User servera-user
   ProxyJump bastion
```