# PyCharm can't connect to a remote behind a gateway (java.net.UnknownHostException)

Tags: java, python, ssh, pycharm, remote-debugging

I try to connect to a remote machine that is behind a gateway for debug and deploy.

By setting `~/.ssh/config` to

```
Host target_machine_name
    ProxyCommand ssh gateway_machine -W %h:%p
```

I can ssh from the command line to that machine (with: `ssh target_machine_name`)

However, when I try to "configure remote python interpreter", I end up with the following error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: target_machine_name
```

Any idea how to forward the communication in a manner that be supported by java.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solved the issue, by replacing the tunneling, with an explicit ssh tunneling command, as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/107682/388429)

```
ssh -N -L localhost:2260:target_machine_name:22 gateway_machine
```

and directing ssh to localhost with port 2260

Comment: Did you add this line to the `.ssh/config` file? as ``` Host target_machine_name
    ProxyCommand ssh -N -L localhost:2260:target_machine_name:22 gateway_machine```

Comment: there's a better explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827685/pycharm-configuring-multi-hop-remote-interpreters-via-ssh/38212999