# How to connect to ssh server from another server

Tags: python, windows, ssh, server, remote-access

I've been trying to connect to first an out-of-band management server (in my case, since I'm connecting to DELL-servers, an iDRAC) and through that connect to the main server itself. I've got it to work when I do it manually, using, in the (windows) terminal:

> putty.exe -ssh 'username'@'iDRAC-IP'

followed by PuTTY window opening where I type in the password, followed by

> connect

which connects to the server itself, and then I type in the username and password for the server, completing the process.

When I've been writing my script in python, I'm using paramiko, http://www.paramiko.org/, suggested here on stackoverflow, and following this example: https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/04/24/execute-shell-commands-over-ssh-using-python-and-paramiko/, and it works just splendid for the iDRAC (the first server I connect to). It also works when I type in

> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('connect')

because I am still in my first server (ssh_client) (I can tell this is working because when I try to connect to the server manually afterwards, it is occupied). But after that it stops working, since when doing 'connect' I am no longer in ssh_client, but in a different server.

So my question is - how do I connect to a server from another server (in this case being the out-of-band management server) and log in to this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh tunnel to do so.
this post may resolve your problem:
*[PyCharm: Configuring multi-hop remote Interpreters via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827685/pycharm-configuring-multi-hop-remote-interpreters-via-ssh)*